# wxPython window IsShownOnScreen but not actually visible

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a `wxPython` gui that sometimes has weird behavior.  I have a button that creates a dialog, then calls `dia.Show()` and `dia.Center()`.  At this point `dia.IsShownOnScreen`, `dia.IsActive`, and `dia.Shown` are all `"true"`, but the dialog is actually nowhere to be found.

Does anyone know any reasons why `IsShownOnScreen` would come up as true, but be incorrect?

I am trying to isolate this problem in the code, but the codebase is large and this problem may take a while to reproduce.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

If the following code is not run while initializing, my dialog window shows up without a problem:

```
        TEXT="choose directory. No spaces are allowed in path!"                                                     
        dia = wx.DirDialog(self, message=TEXT,defaultPath = os.getcwd() ,style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE )                
        result=dia.ShowModal()                                                                                      
        if result == wx.ID_OK:                                                                                      
          self.WD=str(dia.GetPath())                                                                                                         
        dia.Destroy()
```

This piece of code is used if the user runs:

```
    $ program.py
```

instead of specifying a directory in the command line:

```
    $ program.py -WD directory
```

The code above has no obvious relationship to the button and dialog in the main frame of my gui, but this code is definitely what is breaking things.

Comment: It's impossible to tell you much at all without some of the code to go along with your symptoms.  Dialogs behave properly for me and many other wx users.  Perhaps you have something parented inconsistently or incorrectly?  There are lots of possibilities.